# Entities are not persisted when using RepositoryItemWriter with AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-batch

I am trying to copy entites from one DB to another using SpringBatch. My idea is to switch datasources during runtime using `AbstractRoutingDataSource` depending on thread context passed in `ItemReaderListener` methods. When debugging `JobExecution` after job execution completes, it contains correct info about number of rows written and about number of commits. However data are not persisted into database.

I have defined 2 datasources and routing datasource:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSourceRouting() {
    DataSourceRouting dataSourceRouting = new DataSourceRouting(targetDataSource, sourceDataSource);
    Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceContextHolder.DataSourceEnum.SOURCE, sourceDataSource);
    dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceContextHolder.DataSourceEnum.TARGET, targetDataSource);
    dataSourceRouting.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
    dataSourceRouting.setDefaultTargetDataSource(targetDataSource);
    return dataSourceRouting;
}

@Bean("transactionRoutingManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(DataSource dataSourceRouting) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSourceRouting);
    return transactionManager;
}
```

next I have defined reader and writer:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public RepositoryItemReader<DataType> dataTypeReader() {
    RepositoryItemReader<DataType> itemReader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setRepository(dataTypeRepository);
    itemReader.setPageSize(10);
    itemReader.setMethodName("findAll");
    itemReader.setSort(new HashMap<>());
    return itemReader;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public RepositoryItemWriter<DataType> dataTypeWriter() {
    RepositoryItemWriter<DataType> itemWriter = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setRepository(dataTypeRepository);
    return itemWriter;
}
```

and ItemReaderListener to switch DS using thread context:

```
@Override
@BeforeRead
public void beforeRead() {
    DataSourceContextHolder.setBranchContext(DataSourceContextHolder.DataSourceEnum.SOURCE);
}

@Override
@AfterRead
public void afterRead(Object o) {
    DataSourceContextHolder.setBranchContext(DataSourceContextHolder.DataSourceEnum.TARGET);
}
```

finally I have defined step as follows:

```
        Step step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get("DATA_TYPE")
                                      .<DataType, DataType>chunk(10)
                                      .reader(dataTypeReader())
                                      .writer(dataTypeWriter())
                                      .transactionManager(transactionRoutingManager)
                                      .throttleLimit(1)
                                      .startLimit(1)
                                      .listener(new WISItemReadListener())
                                      .build();
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot change the datasource mid-flight, so this won't work. You are probably better of using regular datasources and either 2 repositories with different datasource, or write directly using the `EntityManager` instead of the repository.

Comment: +1 to what M. Deinum said. `My idea is to switch datasources during runtime using AbstractRoutingDataSource depending on thread context passed in ItemReaderListener methods.`: Can you elaborate on the motivation behind that? Can you explain what are your trying to achieve without referring to Spring Batch?

Comment: Well, motivation is to export data from one database to another using JPA repositories and entities provided by external library (jar dependency) without need to create custom repositories. I just wanted to make my life easier and reuse most code I could. However, based on M. Denium comment, I have started creating dummy repositories classes for ItemWritter that uses different entity manager with target datasource.